# UIView setHidden not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard

I am writing an app for the iphone and am attempting to create a view controller with two different views. So I have a subview created on top of the initial view in storyboard. I have created an outlet in the .h for the new view. I want to display the resultsView after the button is pressed so I have the view set to hidden in properties.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
{
UIView *resultsView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *resultsView;
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender;
```

In my .m I have the following code

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize resultsView;

- (IBAction)scanButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
[resultsView setHidden = NO];
}
```

I have also tried

```
resultsView.hidden = NO;
```

Neither of these worked and I tried NSLog to retrieve the BOOL of resultsView.hidden and it was still YES.

Comment: Have you put an NSLog call in the function to make sure it is getting called?  Have you checked that `resultsView` is not nil when that function is called?  Also `[resultsView setHidden = NO];` is not valid syntax, it should be: `[resultsView setHidden:NO];` or `resultsView.hidden = NO;`

Comment: I checked and resultsView is (NULL) Thanks for pointing out the syntax error

Comment: The function isn't getting called. I used NSLog and resultsView.hidden = NO isn't changing the BOOL of resultsView.hidden from YES

Comment: I edited my answer to shed some light on this, I hope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `resultsView` is `NULL` or `nil`, then you did not assign it properly in interface builder, or in code.  Make sure you drag the outlet connection in your storyboard/xib file, or assign it in code somewhere like `viewWillAppear`

If the function isn't getting called, then the action is not linked up to the button in interface builder. To make sure it is connected properly, you can ctrl+click (or right click) and drag from the button to the view controller, and select `scanButtonTapped` from the "Sent actions" list that appears

Comment: Ok I redid the outlet connection from resultsView to the .h and it worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Another option - check that you run your `[? setHidden:]` code in UIThread

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that `resultsView` id nil when you try and set the hidden property.

Please, review your code to initialize `resultsView` and if you need more help, post some relevant part of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you are designing a `@IBDesignable` `UIView` and you are using swift, somehow `view.hidden = isHidden` just does not work.

The work around is the following.

```
view.setValue(isHidden, forKey: "hidden")
```

I hope this helps someone out there.